# Remove 'portfolio' from URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy, views

I was trying to remove **portfolio-view** from url and followed instructions to remove its name from highlighted section. This works but has left me with '**portfolio**' now even though field is blank. What is wrong with this code or need changing in breadcrumbs please? It is now grabbing 'portfolio' from somewhere and i want this hidden in url.

I'm trying to get: `http://www.sitename.com/post` instead of `http//www.sitename.com/portfolio/post`.

```
/* Portfolio */

 function my_post_type_portfolio() {

 register_post_type( 'portfolio',

 array(

 'label' => __('Portfolio'),

 'singular_label' => __('Porfolio Item', 'theme'),

 '_builtin' => false,

 'public' => true,

 'show_ui' => true,

 'show_in_nav_menus' => true,

 'capability_type' => 'page',

 'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/images/icon_portfolio.png',

**'rewrite' => array(
 'slug' => ' ',
 'with_front' =>false,**
 ),

 'supports' => array(

 'title',

 'editor',

 'thumbnail',

 'excerpt',

 'custom-fields',

 'comments')

 )
 );
 register_taxonomy('portfoliocat', 'portfolio', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Portfolio Categories', 'singular_name' => 'Category', "rewrite" => true, "query_var" => true));
 }


add_action('init', 'my_post_type_portfolio');
```

Breadcrumb setting is: `<a title="Go to %title%." href="%link%">%htitle%</a>`

Permalinks: `/%postname%/`

Comment: What plug-in are you using for your breadcrumbs? Breadcrumb NavXT?

Comment: Yes using Breadcrumb NavXT

Comment: Just installed a plug-in 'remove custom post types' and that has solved the problem. don't know how it works, but it works. perfect url's now

Answer (score 0):

You could try this plugin I wrote: https://github.com/interconnectit/custom-post-type-permalinks